# visual studio 2013 solution explorer list duplicated files after nuget restore

Tags: angularjs, git, visual-studio-2013

The Project Explorer has duplicated/triplicated lists for scripts and css which are specified in the Package.config.  The .csproj also has duplicated/triplicated <content Include="..."> under <ItemGroup>for these files, even the physical files are not duplicated.  I have to manually remove the duplicated/triplicated files. Is there a way to prevent this?

The project is under GIT source control.  All additional packages that can be restored by Nuget are not tracked(checked) in the GIT repository.  When I do a PULL from the GIT repository, all the Angular related scripts and css have yellow triangle icons.  The files are downloaded by Nuget during build time. Though I can add those packages to be source controlled so Nuget won't download these scripts/css every time during a build, this is against the source control practice.

[image]

Nuget Package Manager settings 
[image]

Here is the package.config

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Angular.UI.Bootstrap" version="0.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Angular.UI.UI-Router" version="0.2.15" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.4.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angular-ui-grid" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="JasmineTest" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NugetPackageRestore" version="1.0.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap.Less" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>`
```

Comment: Can you provide specific examples of triplicate script and css with folder locations? Do you ever move default locations for your NuGet-installed javascript and css (such as Bootstrap)?

Comment: No, I didn't change the default locations for scripts and css.  I wish I could but there doesn't seem to be a way.